# Spring Data JPA filtering

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a controller which is like below.

```
public String getAccountsFilter(
    @PathVariable("cardHolderId") String cardHolderId,
    @RequestParam(value = "accountType", required = false) String accountType,
    @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name)
```

The AccountEntity is as below

```
public class AccountEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long           serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String                      id;
    private String                      accounttype;
    private Date                        endDate;
    private boolean                     active;
    private PlanEntity                  planEntity;
    private Set<TransactionEntryEntity> transactionEntry = new HashSet<TransactionEntryEntity>();
```

I did the filtering for `id` and `accountType` which is easy using `findByIdAndAccountType()` method, and the query is generated automatically.

But if i want to filter using `id` and `name` which is property of `Plan (AccountEntity.PlanEntity.name)`, it is not straightforward since `name` is from the child table. How can i approach for this criteria?

Comment: You can annotate the method `findByIdAndPlanEntityName` in the `AccountEntityRepository` using JPQL or SQL query that joins AccountEntity and PlanEntity and returns the list of AccountEntity objects that match the criteria. This might help you http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume PlanEntity and TransactionEntryEntity is being annotated by @OneToOne or @OneToMany etc

You may do the following in one of the method in the repository of AccountEntity

```
@Query("select a from AccountEntity a where a.planEntity.name = :name")
public aMethod( @Param("name") String name)
```